How to create an Athena view of the latest partition
I have a partitioned Athena table, and I want to create a view that only contains the latest partition of that table. Here's my query:
CREATE OR REPLACE VIEW latest_partition_data AS
SELECT * 
FROM data
WHERE partition_0 = (SELECT partition_0 FROM "data$partitions" ORDER BY partition_0 DESC LIMIT 1)

And I received this error:
Table '{AwsAccountId}.{Database}.data$partitions' does not exist
I've made sure that 'data' is in fact a partition table my running
SELECT * 
FROM data
WHERE partition_0 = (SELECT partition_0 FROM "data$partitions" ORDER BY partition_0 DESC LIMIT 1)

and the query does produce rows from the latest partition.
